# Creating a social game with facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am creating a game for android devices where I want to integrate a social matchmaking system like Wordfeud, Draw Something, etc. The only problem is that I can't manage to find any good SDK that offers exactly what I want, so I thought that there might be another solution.

So what I'm asking is: is there any way to integrate a social matchmaking system for my game with only facebook sdk or together with a sdk that doesn't have so many demands on the developer?

What I want is that the players should be able to connect with facebook and challenge their friends in a turn-based game. No virtual currency, no achievements or any of that stuff. Just the ability to challenge each others.

I've looked into several social SDKs:

- OpenFeint - Good reputation, but no longer in service.
- GREE - Not what I wanted.
- ScoreLoop - You had to become their personal slave.
- Swarm - Too high demands and no facebook support.

Is there any SDK that I've missed? Is there anything out there that fullfills my needs or do I have to integrate what I want without any helpful SDKs? If I have to do it myself, where and how should I start?

Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360909/android-games-development-sdk)?

Comment: I'm sorry but that is out of the question. The game is almost complete. The only thing missing is the multiplayer-feature. :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have missed out [ScoreNinja](http://scoreninja.appspot.com/), but that is extremely simple and no integration with anything. Other than that there is [ScoreLoop](http://www.scoreloop.com/), which is good, a little heavy, but you can truncate parts that you don't want to use. Otherwise you can directly use what Facebook offers you, which you can read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/).

Comment: I'm afraid that is not what I was asking for. I want the playes to be able to compete against each other in game-sessions, not publish their score. I wrote that I had checked out ScoreLoop and I did not appreciate their methods.

Comment: The other two probably although not useful; I believe ScoreLoop and SocialLoop(As given in your question) are different.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. It was supposed to say ScoreLoop, not SocialLoop in the question. My bad.